# HTML/CSS border grow with overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border

I seem to have a problem understanding how borders are actually sized. Please assume the following HTML/CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="height: 100vh; margin: 0; padding: 0; display:flex">
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; border: solid 1px black; min-height: 0; min-width: 0;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                <div style="border: solid 1px red;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex-grow: 10; border: solid 1px black;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The red border always is as wide as the div with "flex-grow: 1" and not as wide as the text "abcd...". And I do not understand why, nor how I could fix it. As I understand it the red border should fully surround the text as there is enough space since the overflow delivers it. Can anyone explain why it doesn't? Why does it always use the width of the div with "flex-grow: 1"?

Kind regards

PS: its the same with every browser

Comment: what do you expect? `flex-grow: 1;` willr esize an element to fill the remaining space. It has nothign to do with the border. A broder will always have its declared size on the existign element. it does not resize an element. The size of your element in your case is determined by `flex-grow` (fillign remainign space) and not the content like normally. A border will surrond an element itself not the childs content.

Comment: I would expext the red border to surround the text since that grows into the overflow area as expected. Whey doesnt the text get cut off there, too? And would I achieve that the text gets fully surrounded by the border?

Comment: a border surrounds the element its used on. the text is not an element. Its a content of the div element. So why should the broder suoorund the text? liek I said its not an element and it makes no logical sense that a border would display inside an element.

Comment: okay I understand that there is a difference between an element and its content. But do you understand what I wish to achieve and could you tell me how, please? I still have no clue

Comment: yes, like I said, sementicly a broder will always surround an element not tis content. So you have to wrap the text inside an own element (like a span or paragraph) and apply the border to that element instead. Or dont use `flex-grow` so that the div will have the size of its content and not getting resized by `flex-grow`.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Adding a span inside the div sorrounding the text and giving it the border (instead of the div) did it

Answer (score 1):

Semanticly a broder will always surrond the element its applied to. Thats the evry definition of a broder. Your text is not an alement but the content of the element. To have the border to apply to the text, you need to wrap the text in an own element like a `<span>`. then apply the border to the span instead.

```html
<div style="border: solid 1px black;">
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div><span style="border: solid 1px red;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` you essentially say: "So the initial main size of the item should be 0, but I want to set the grow factor to 1 in relationship with the main item". The end will look like the example you showed.

Since I don't now what you want to accomplish, you just said you want to surround the text with the red border, and I suppose you want to see the whole text, just delete the `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` that should do the trick.

Comment: this was not the question here. OP does want to know why a border is surrounding the element (div)  instead of its content. It has nothign to do with flex-grow in the first place. Just semantics that the OP doesnt understand.

Comment: No I want a scroll bar when the text is too long. But I want want the red border to always surround the text no matter if it overflows the parent element or not